# Array variable in another array variable

Tags: flash, object, multidimensional-array

Sorry if the title is a little confusing. Here's what I meant - I have an array and and object. Let me give a visual:

This is my object:

```
obj["id"] = ["1","2","3"];
obj["name"] = ["na","no","ne"];
```

my itemArray:

```
itemArray = ["id","name"];
```

And now, I want to retrieve the items in the object, I tried

```
for (var i:int = 0; i<objLen; i++)
{
    for (var j:int = 0; j<count; j++)
    {
        textBox_txt.appendText(obj.arr[i][j]);
    }
}
```

but it doesn't work. How do I actually use the arr[i] variable in the array? :s

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps something like this:

```
var array:Array;
var count:int;
for( var i:int = 0; i < itemArray.length; i++ )
{
    array = obj[ itemArray[ i ] ];
    count = array.length;
    for ( var j:int = 0; j<count; j++ )
    {
        textBox_txt.appendText( array[ j ] );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I just found this out. jeremynealbrown's answer works but there's also another way to go it: http://www.kirupa.com/forum/showpost.php?p=2596002&postcount=2

```
var obj = new Object();
obj["id"] = ["1","2","3"];
obj["name"] = ["na","no","ne"];
obj["sasdf"] = "asdfa asdfasdf asdf asdf af";

for (var i in obj)
{
       if (obj[i] is Array)
       {
               for (var j:int = 0; j<obj[i].length; j++)
               {
                       trace(obj[i][j]);
                       //textBox_txt.appendText(obj.arr[i][j]);
               }

       }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Essentially, using two [ ] operators to access nested arrays is correct, but you are confusing the way the arrays are put together:

1. Your first object has **two named properties**, "id" and "name", **each contain one-dimensional arrays**:

   ```
   var obj:Object = {
       id:["1", "2", "3"],
       name:["na", "no", "ne"];
   }
   ```

   *( I use this notation to make things more readable - it creates the same object as your code. Notice the { } and [ ] brackets!)*
2. Your itemArray is a one-dimensional array, which has only two strings inside, but **it does not appear anywhere else in the code**.

   ```
   itemArray = ["id", "name"];
   ```
3. Your for loop **iterates over the property "arr" of the obj Object**, which does not exist:

   ```
   for (var i:int = 0; i<objLen; i++)
   {
       for (var j:int = 0; j<count; j++)
       {
           textBox_txt.appendText(obj.arr[i][j]); // obj has properties "id" and "name", but not "arr"
       }
   }
   ```

Now forget everything above.  This is how you could do it right:

1. If you wanted a **two-dimensional array**, you could omit the property names:

   ```
   var arr:Array= [ 
                      ["1", "na"], 
                      ["2", "no"], 
                      ["3", "ne"]
                  ];
   ```

   *(Note: This has a nested sets of [ ] operators, no { } brackets!)*
   and iterate like this:

   ```
   for (var i:int = 0; i<arr.length; i++)
   {
       for (var j:int = 0; j<arr[i].length; j++)
       {
           textBox_txt.appendText(arr[i][j]);
       }
   } // output: 1na2no3ne
   ```
2. You could also use named properties to make things look nice, and your code more readable:

   ```
   var itemArray:Array = [ 
       {id:"1", name:"na"}, 
       {id:"2", name:"no"}, 
       {id:"3", name:"ne"} 
   ];
   ```

   *(Notice how the [ ] and { }  brackets have changed places!)*

   This is a **one-dimensional array containing 3 objects**, each with properties "id" and "name".  You could then iterate to append the individual object names to your text like this:

   ```
   for each ( var obj:Object in itemArray) {
       textBox_txt.appendText(obj.id + "" + obj.name);
   } // output: 1na2no3ne
   ```